# Is it possible to enalbe SOAP with OAuth for Group and Professional editions?

Tags: api, oauth2, soap

Does anyone know is it possible to enable SOAP API for Group and Professional editions with OAuth 2.0 (connected app) authentication?

I cannot find this info directly in the documentation. What stated is the following:

1. *You can also request that a connected app be whitelisted to use the REST API in GE or PE organizations.* --- This is only about REST.
2. *SOAP based Web services can be enabled using an API token called a Client ID, which needs to be appended to your SOAP headers in integration calls. This special key enables your app to successfully make calls to GE/PE even if the customer does not have API access.* --- It is not clear will SOAP API work with OAuth access token or only via direct credentials login.

Thanks in advance!

Regards,
Vitaly

Comment: Client ID is for ISVs to bypass the PE API restriction, and only available through special arrangement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will work (Assuming you have somehow gotten API access on PE, which is a licensing arrangement with Salesforce) however you need to ensure the OAuth setup includes the appropriate 'api' scope:

http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_scopes.htm&language=en_US

The appropriate bit:

> The scope parameter enables you to fine-tune what the client
> application can access in a Salesforce organization. The valid values
> for scope are:
>
> **api**
>
> Allows access to the current,
> logged-in user’s account using APIs, such as REST API and Bulk API.
> This value also includes chatter_api, which allows access to Chatter
> REST API resources.

'Such as' also includes the SOAP API.

Comment: Thanks, Steven. So I suppose that I will receive ClientID as a result of licensing arrangement which can be done after security review, right? Yes, in almost all places I find REST API notion and SOAP is masked under "Such as" or sort of phrases. That is why I decided to clarify.